# Flex Mobile How to pass info from Page One (List.selectedItem) to the third page?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, flex4.5

I have 3 pages view,

1. HomeView
2. ViewPg02
3. ViewPg03

In **HomeView**, has a List control and when user select an item it will goes to ViewPg02

```
protected function myList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void    {
                navigator.pushView(views.ViewPg02, myList.selectedItem, null);  }
```

In **ViewPg02**, has an image control and it get the image display info from myList.selectedItem

```
<s:Image id="imageScreen1" width="100%" height="100%"  
                 source="images/{data.image}"
```

and when user click on the picture, it will go to ViewPg03  with the following code:

```
protected function imageScreen_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void  {
                navigator.pushView(ViewPg03); 
                    }
```

Problem: I get a blank page in ViewPg03 and I can’t use myList.selectedItem in ViewPg02.

How do it get the same image in ViewPg02 to display in ViewPg03 ?

Thanks.

Comment: The best approach would be maintaining a model and keeping your data in that model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just continue to pass the data along to page 3?

```
navigator.pushView(ViewPg03, data);
```

Doing this will pass the `data` property again to page three and you can display the image the same way.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: you are right. Wow, such a simple solution and its take me sometime to search for it. thanks man.